how to import config file in spring that outside of classpath
i have following repository structure for my spring config server:
repository structure for config files
and i want to import config named "jwt_secrets.properties" in multiple services, so i'm trying to import it inside /{application}/{application}-{profile}.yml:
enter image description here
but this doesn't work
how can i do this so i keep my jwtSigningKey(which im trying to import) in one file, so i dont mess up when i want to change it?
i tried using "^/jwt_secrets.properties" but this also doesn't work.

Don't post code as images but post code as code with proper tags/formatting.

using 2 dots helped me with this
https://i.sstatic.net/trM53CUy.png

Please post code as code not as links to images.
